# Suggestions on how to speed up 12.04?

Tags: 12.04

I use Thinkpad x100e: AMD Athlon Neo X2 1.6 GHz, RAM 4GB (3.6 GB available).

I installed 12.04 64-bit (with Windows installer) on 40GB of hard disk space. I have some problem about lag speed of the OS.
Can anyone suggest me how to disable or turn off any feature to increase the speed performance of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

I would install either Lubuntu or Xubuntu which use the resource light LXDE & XFCE desktop environments.  Also a full install will always run faster than Wubi.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether there are proprietary graphics drivers for your machine and if yes, install them. They are non-open-source but their performance is sometimes much better.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use Unity as Desktop Environgment of the main Ubuntu distribution. 4GB RAM should be more than enough even for Unity or KDE. Something is not right here. Anyway, install other DE like Xfce and KDE and see if there are differences.

Answer (score 0):

Trying out lighter Desktop Environments (LXDE, XFCE, etc.) is one way to go, and will probably yield the greatest noticeable difference in performance.

If, however, you are taken with Unity and want to stick with it, there are a few things you can do to speed things up a bit:

1) Choose "Unity 2D" at login instead of "Unity", if you don't mind going without desktop effects.

2) In Startup Applications, uncheck applications and processes that you don't need Ubuntu to automatically start for you at login (e.g. Bluetooth Manager if you don't have bluetooth, UbuntuOne if you don't use it, programs you simply don't use etc.) Before doing this, first make hidden startup applications visible in the manager:

```
sudo sed -i ‘s/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g’ /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop
```

3) Install Preload, which detects the applications and processes you most frequently use and loads the binaries and dependencies for those applications ahead of time so they load faster:

```
sudo apt-get install preload
```

4) Make sure to update frequently. From time to time, it is also useful to remove .deb files and applications/libraries that are no longer necessary:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```